# thread parallel to other process java

Tags: java, multithreading

i have periodic thread that runs every one second and refers the application. the problem is when the thread is running cpu usage goes up and program respond very bad it seems CPU fan is working with full power. maybe there is a problem with using a infinite while here. is there any other way for doing it?

```
  Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              try {
                while (connect.isDisable()){
                  refresher(rx);
                  Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
              } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
            }
          };
       Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
       thr1.start();
```

if there an alternate way that thhis sets of functions run every one secounds parallel to other process and event handlers respond just like normal?

Comment: It is probably better to use a `Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of putting the thread to sleep.  What does `refresher` do? Is it processor intensive?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse or a similar IDE it won't end a process when you start a new one be default, so you could just have tons of instances of the same code running at once and driving your fan nuts.

Comment: @bradimus  it reads a line from serial port and parse it and update the charts in the application with new data

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, `thread` is a sequence of execution of statements or code in a program and is nothing hardware. It is a flow of execution which takes place.

> A thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler, which is typically a part of the operating system.

And yes, multiple `threads` may run at the same time if your CPU has more than one core. This will of course increase the CPU usage because multiple processes or sequence of codes are running at the same time. You are asking the CPU to perform 2 or more things at the same time and therefore, over usage is an obvious consequence.

About the fan, may be designed to run faster when CPU usage is higher so that the excess heat generated is driven out efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for information. but refresher is only a small piece of code and not very heavy one..so what is the benefit of thread when this small piece of code makes my cpu crazy. I am using macbook pro retina so my CPU is not a low speed one.
can u advice a new piece of code that do the same thing but more efficienly in the background of the application in a way that user wont understand?